# Philosophy - Is Nietzsche's Eternal Return theory true?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, time, physics

Is Nietzsche's Eternal Return theory true? I am extremely worried that it is because of the very likely fact that Einstein's Block Universe theory is true, and what renders Einstein's Block Universe theory even more likely to be true is that the theory of Relativity just got confirmed. - [Relativity Confirmed][1] [1]: http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/d-brief/2018/07/26/revealed-how-black-holes-suck-the-energy-of-nearby-starlight/#.W1w8Li3L3I1

If the Past, Present, and Future all exist in exactly the same way, then every single moment would be a ‘Now’ moment for me. it would also mean that me being dead in the future is equally real in the exact same way as me being alive right Now is real. And since the Past is as real as the Present and future, me being alive in the Past is equally real as me being alive right Now.

If that is the case, then does that mean after I eventually grow old and die, in which my brain will decay and I will no longer be conscious, in other words I cease to exist.

Wouldn’t that mean that I will be alive again but with no memory of what happened since me in the Past is alive in exactly the same way as I am right ‘Now’? if so then under the Block Universe life does repeat and it proves Nietzsche’s “Eternal Return” theory to be true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Philosophy - Does the block universe theory of time mean that life will repeat after death?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/philosophy-does-the-block-universe-theory-of-time-mean-that-life-will-repeat-a)

Comment: You've asked 6 versions of the same question in the last few days, with 5 answers between them.  I appreciate that this issue is weighing heavily on your mind and impacting your mental health.  But you can't keep re-asking the same question repeatedly.  If you create a new question, it needs to be clear how it goes beyond the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

So, I answer here because I don't have enough reputation to comment, and I feel I can help a little at least.

First of all, let me be a bit fussy, because Einstein's theory of general relativity hasn't just been proven, in any case it was in 1919, when a solar eclipse provided data that matched with Einstein's gravitational theory, while it didn't match Newton's. Anyway, things like this don't "prove" a theory, they just show that this theory is in a high level of reliability applicable to these cases. And I assume that the article you linked talked about gravitational waves, which was a consequence derived from Einstein's theory, so yeah, they reinforced even more this theory. Sorry for this long unnecessary paragraph.

Moving on, I haven't ever heard about this block universe until now, and after having read about it (btw if you have some link that gives a detailed explanation feel free to share it, because everything I found was garbage), as I was saying, after having read about it, I don't know how this picture of the universe can be derived from Einstein's theory (and no, this block universe clearly wasn't developed by Einstein, if he did this theory would be much more developed). Apart from this, I can't see either why you related the block universe to the eternal return.

Jumping to the philosophycal part, why would you have to "be alive again" once you die? From what I understood about what you said, you mean, that as your "present consciousness" exists, so does a lot of other "past and future consciousnesses" (man this plural sure is strange), and so when you die you'll jump to these other (past) consciousnesses and live the same all over again, right? Well, I don't know how you got to the idea that you'll regain another consciousness when you die, but I think (and this is purely speculative) that since you're not feeling these other consciousnesses right now (cause you don't right? You're not reading this comment and eating the lunch with two consciousnesses at once right?) then I think that when you die, you die, and this will be it.

Then, since I've read some of your other questions, let me answer some of them too. The most widely accepted type of universe by the scientific community (aka us physicists, yeah call me moron all th rest) is that in the universe will end by what's called heat death, which I just know what you can read anywhere like Wikipedia, because trying to know more without the math makes no sense. Anyway, if you're worried about if the universe is some kind of loop and you'll live your life again and these things, know that it's highly unlikely, since it needs for the total entropy of the universe to reduce, which if you asked a hundred things what can never happen in the universe, 99 would tell you that its entropy can't be reduced, and the other one that neuroscience will never stop being considered a pseudoscience (I'm kidding I read some things about neurosciences actually).

Finally, since you've said also that you're anxious and you are or were depressed and these things I'll end with a positive comment. I went through some really difficult times and suffered depression too. I know that it's like being inside a well and sometimes maybe somebody throws a rope to you, but you don't use it cause of fear that they may drop it just to laugh at you, and in the end they get tired and stop trying to help you. But, well, know that you can get through this tough situation. What worked best for me was to change all my environment for me (which was when I jumped from high school to college, when I went to the furthest university I could). Try to think only about the good things, not the bad ones. And don't get obsessed with philosophycal thoughts, try to read some fantasy or something, although it's good to meditate from time to time, don't overdo it. And you can always seek help on the Internet, there's good people. To sentence it, I'll just leave [this link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCm7iK3MSQM) which I've found this afternoon and has cheered me up.